# Vue js using asset path for images in components

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am using Vue js 3 to create a webpage.

My (SingleFile) component:

```
<template>
  <img
    alt="Vue logo"
    src="{{ img_url }}"
    class="-mr-16 object-cover image-focus"
  />
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import { Options, Vue } from "vue-class-component";

@Options({
  props: {
    img_url: String
  },
})
export default class HelloWorld extends Vue {
  msg!: string;
}
</script>
```

The way I call it:

```
<CatchImage img_url="@/assets/images/Image.jpg" />


<script lang="ts">
import { Options, Vue } from "vue-class-component";
import Image from "@/components/Image.vue";

@Options({
  components: {
    Image,
  },
})
</script>
```

This does not load the image. Instead I get an error. Ich I replace the variabvle with the actual path it works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
<CatchImage :img_url="require(`@/assets/images/Image.jpg`)" />
```

Also in template use **:src** instead of **src**
like this:

```
:src="img_url"
```

Comment: Still does not work. instead of a replacement. It gets rendered as ```<img alt="Vue logo" src="{{ img_url }}" class="-mr-16 object-cover image-focus" data-v-1ba4efab="">```

Comment: Sorry overlooked template part. I edited my answer